# Яндекс апи: Как определить город?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, геолокация

```
<script src="<ключ>&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">

ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation
    geolocation.get({
        provider: '213.110.97.151',
        mapStateAutoApply: true
    }).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        })
}
```

В итоге получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, координаты определяет. Но как определить именно город?

Comment: Не уверен, но попробуйте `result.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('metaDataProperty.GeocoderMetaData.AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.SubAdministrativeArea.Locality.LocalityName'`

Comment: Работает. Как Вы его определили?)

Comment: Оформите, как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы не поверите, поискал в Google в течение 2 минут :)

Comment: хм, это я так плохо гуглил, что ли((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
result.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('metaDataProperty.GeocoderMetaData.AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.SubAdministrativeArea.Locality.LocalityName'
```